# How to do error handling of nested `.iter()`s?

Tags: rust

I am trying to do error handling when using `.iter()` in combination with `.flat_map`, which has an `.iter().map()` within it.

The scenario is getting all the `Event`s that belong to a set of organisations, where the nested `.iter().map()` is used to get the participants of each event, combine that with the event and return an `EventResponse` stuct.

A non-specific-scenario way of describing the issue would be 'How to get `Result<Vec<T>, err>` from nested flat_map of `Result<Vec<T>, err>`, which has nested map of `Result<T, err>`'

Below is an abstracted/simplified version of the code I'm using, that gives me the same errors as my actual code.

```rust
struct Event {
    id: usize,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct EventResponse {
    id: usize,
    participants: Vec<i32>,
}

fn main() {
    let orgs = vec![1, 3, 14, 12];

    let events: Result<Vec<EventResponse>, &str> = orgs
        .iter()
        .flat_map::<Result<Vec<EventResponse>, &str>, _>(|org_id| {
            get_events_for(*org_id)
                .map_err(|_| "That Org id does not exist")
                .map(|events| {
                    events
                        .iter()
                        .map::<Result<EventResponse, &str>, _>(|event| {
                            get_event_with_participants(event)
                                .map(|event_response| event_response)
                                .map_err(|_| "Participants for that event were not found")
                        })
                        .collect()
                })
        })
        .collect();
}

fn get_events_for(id: usize) -> Result<Vec<Event>, ()> {
    // pretend we are checking against a database of existing org ids, if the org id does not exist, then return an error
    if id == 3 {
        Ok(vec![Event { id }])
    } else {
        Err(())
    }
}

fn get_event_with_participants(event: &Event) -> Result<EventResponse, ()> {
    //pretend the participants are fetched from a database
    let foundParticipants = true;
    if foundParticipants {
        Ok(EventResponse {
            id: event.id,
            participants: vec![1, 2, 5],
        })
    } else {
        Err(())
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5d408c00cb3276425bad883d19047e05)

The type annotations are to show what is expected to be returned at each stage. I expect `events` to be of type `Result<Vec<EventResponse>, &str>` but I am getting 2 errors:

```rust
error[E0277]: a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<EventResponse>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `std::result::Result<EventResponse, &str>`
  --> example.rs:27:26
   |
27 |                         .collect()
   |                          ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<EventResponse>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=std::result::Result<EventResponse, &str>>`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<std::result::Result<EventResponse, &str>>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<EventResponse>`

error[E0277]: a collection of type `std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<EventResponse>, &str>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `std::vec::Vec<EventResponse>`
  --> example.rs:30:10
   |
30 |         .collect();
   |          ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<EventResponse>, &str>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=std::vec::Vec<EventResponse>>`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<std::vec::Vec<EventResponse>>` is not implemented for `std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<EventResponse>, &str>`
```

EDIT: The `get_events_for` function **cannot be modified**, however, the `get_event_with_participants` function **can be modified**, if that helps.

Comment: This is what [try_fold](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_fold) and [try_for_each](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_for_each) are for.

Comment: @Anler from what I understand, you're suggesting I replace the maps and flat map with try_fold or try_for_each ... but the docs you've linked don't explain how/if you can get the error out from nested iterators...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being interested in the problem, I tried to implement this with `map` and `try_fold`. Using `flat_map` directly didn't work for me, as I couldn't get around the fact that the first inner loop has to produce a `Result`. I moved the error messages into the functions, but that could easily be undone if you explicitly wanted to avoid it.

```
struct Event {
    id: usize,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct EventResponse {
    id: usize,
    participants: Vec<i32>,
}

fn main() {
    let orgs = vec![1, 3, 14, 12];

    let events: Result<Vec<EventResponse>, &str> = orgs
        .iter()
        .map(|org_id| {
            get_events_for(*org_id)?
                .iter()
                .map(get_event_with_participants)
                .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()
        })
        .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()
        .map(|org_responses| org_responses.into_iter().flatten().collect());
}

fn get_events_for(id: usize) -> Result<Vec<Event>, &'static str> {
    // pretend we are checking against a database of existing org ids, if the org id does not exist, then return an error
    if id == 3 {
        Ok(vec![Event { id }])
    } else {
        Err("That Org id does not exist")
    }
}

fn get_event_with_participants(event: &Event) -> Result<EventResponse, &'static str> {
    //pretend the participants are fetched from a database
    let foundParticipants = true;
    if foundParticipants {
        Ok(EventResponse {
            id: event.id,
            participants: vec![1, 2, 5],
        })
    } else {
        Err("Participants for that event were not found")
    }
}
```

For `try_fold`, the main function would become:

```rust
fn main() {
    let orgs = vec![1, 3, 14, 12];

    let events: Result<Vec<EventResponse>, &str> =
        orgs.iter().try_fold(Vec::new(), |mut responses, &org| {
            responses = get_events_for(org)?
                .into_iter()
                .try_fold(responses, |mut responses, event| {
                    let response = get_event_with_participants(&event)?;
                    responses.push(response);
                    Ok(responses)
                })?;
            Ok(responses)
        });
}
```

Personally I'm a fan of the `map` version, as modifying a `Vec` using `try_fold` feels awkward since you have to return the accumulator despite modifying the `Vec` directly.

Another version to consider is to just use loops, which appears to be far simpler in this situation since you can use the `?` operator for errors:

```rust
fn main() {
    let orgs = vec![1, 3, 14, 12];

    let events = get_all_responses(orgs);
}

fn get_all_responses(
    orgs: impl IntoIterator<Item = usize>,
) -> Result<Vec<EventResponse>, &'static str> {
    let mut responses = Vec::new();
    for org in orgs.into_iter() {
        for event in get_events_for(org)? {
            responses.push(get_event_with_participants(&event)?)
        }
    }
    Ok(responses)
}
```